# Unbound Variable error in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to do a function that removes duplicates from a list using Common Lisp on LispWorks.

So I did two functions. The first one "remove-e" removes an element from a list and a second one "remove-rep" uses the first one to return a list without duplicates.

Here is my code for the first one:

```
(defun remove-e (L e)
  (if (null L)
    L
    (if (= e (car L))
      (remove-e (cdr L) e)
      (cons (car L) (remove-e (cdr L) e)))))
```

It works good when given a list of numbers but when I give it letters, I get this error:

```
(remove-e '(a a b a d a g a h t) a)

Error: The variable A is unbound.
```

For my second function:

```
(defun remove-rep (l)    
  (if (null l)
    l
    (cons (car l)
          (remove-rep (remove-e (cdr l) (car l))))))
```

This is the error message that I get when trying to test it:

```
CL-USER 12 : 6 > (remove-rep '(1 2 3 1 5 1 1))

Error: The variable   is unbound.
```

I saw that there are some similar questions, but couldn't find the common points of my program with these:
[Unbound variable in Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38453038/unbound-variable-in-lisp) , 
[Unbound variable in Common Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400850/unbound-variable-in-common-lisp)

Comment: The `=` function is for comparing numbers. Use `eql` if you want to be able to compare numbers or symbols, use `equal` if you want to be able to compare things like strings and lists.

Comment: You have some Arabic characters after `defun remove-rep (l)`. They're Unicode code point `0x8a0`.

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/8a0/index.htm

Comment: @Barmar even with `eql` and `equal` I'm getting the same error. How to remove the Arabic characters?

Comment: You'll also need to quote the `a` symbol to prevent it being evaluated as a variable.

Comment: @Benz Delete them in the text editor you're using to write the program.

Comment: Why do you develop in debug level 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`remove-e` only works with a list of numbers, because you're using `=` to compare elements. If you want to be able to work with symbols as well, use `eql`:

```
(defun remove-e (L e)
  (if (null L) L
    (if (eql e (car L)) (remove-e (cdr L) e)
      (cons (car L) (remove-e (cdr L) e)))))
```

Then when you call it, you have to quote the symbol argument, to prevent it from being evaluated as a variable.

```
(remove-e '(a a b a d a g a h t) 'a)
```

The problem in `remove-rep` is that you somehow typed some non-printing, multi-byte characters at the end of the first line. It works correctly with those characters removed. Try retyping the function, or just copy/paste this:

```
(defun remove-rep (l)
  (if (null l) l
    (cons (car l) (remove-rep (remove-e (cdr l) (car l))))))
```

BTW, Lisp programmers don't generally put `)` on new lines like you do, they put them at the end of the line like this.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications! It works fine now. I was just wondering where those characters come from? Obviously I was not programming in Arabic.

Comment: I have no idea, you must have inadvertently types characters with the Alt key.

Comment: I have one more question please. What paradigm seems best suited for this problem? Is it when using Lisp or Prolog?

Comment: I haven't done much Prolog programming, but I think it's best suited to problems that involve pattern matching or filling in blanks. Procedural languages like Lisp can only solve a problem in one direction: you give it parameters X and Y and it calculates a result Z. In Prolog, you can give X and Z, and it will try to find Y.

Comment: Based on that, can we say that Prolog is more suited since it gives us more options and we are not stuck in only one direction?

Comment: More suited for what? They're good for different types of applications. Prolog is usually used for searching structured data. E.g. you can have a data set that represents family relationships, and then easily query "Who is the father of Jim" or "Who is the son of Fred".